# Optimize data acquisition with HDF5 files in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, nidaqmx

I'm trying to understand how can I write a DAQ in Python where I manage two signals (I and Q from an IQ mixer) from a NI device. My doubt concern two problems:

1. What are the main differences to use `h5py` instead of `pandas`? My data are not complex, I need only two matrices datasets, one for the **I signal** and one for the **Q signal**.
2. Is it more efficient to create the whole dataset and then occupy a lot of memory before storing it in an HDF5 file, or to open the HDF5 file each time to add a new row (new data) to the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

@Frostman, this is primarily an opinion question. Remember, "*Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.*"

The question about memory use is the more important consideration. The answer depends on memory required to hold your data (and if you have enough before writing to disk). Creating the whole dataset in memory is faster and easier. But, that's not an option if it doesn't fit. :-) Note: you don't want to write data 1 row at a time. That is the slowest way to work with HDF5 data. If you need to save incrementally, write "a lot" of rows at 1 time (say 1,000).

There is a related consideration: which of these packages is fast enough (& easy enough) to keep up with I/O requirement to data acquisition?  (I have no expertise in this areas, but know high sample rates will quickly create a lot of data.)

From a technical perspective, the difference in the packages is "cosmetic" (IMHO). (FYI, you can also use PyTables to create HDF5 data.) In other words, all 3 can easily create a HDF5 file with the data described in your question. The question (for you), is which package do you want to learn? And, which package do you plan use for later post-processing? (I assume you want to open the file and "do something" with the data later.)

All else being equal, I would to create the data with the same package I plan to use for downstream processing. Why? `h5py` and `pandas` use different schema to store the data. So, reading the data will be easier if you write and read with the same package. (That said, you can manipulate HDF5 data between the packages.)

If the downstream processing requirement has not been decided, I would select `h5py` if either of these are true: a) you are comfortable with NumPy, or b) you need to use NumPy for other operations. `h5py` is pretty easy to learn if you know NumPy.

Otherwise, you might prefer `pandas`. Many claim it is easier to use (vs h5py and PyTables). I am not a pandas expert, so can't comment. I prefer h5py and PyTables primarly because the 2d data schema is saved in a table format that is easy to review with HDFView. (Also, I use NumPy 90+% of the time, so h5py/PyTables are natural extensions.)

If you want to compare code for each, look at the answers to this question: [How to write large multiple arrays to a h5 file in layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71335363/10462884) They show code required to store data similar to yours for all 3 packages: h5py, pytables and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when acquiring long measurements, it is handy to write directly into an HDF5 file. This is my preferred way, because any interrupt (power failure etc.) wont result in data loss.

This is my solution using a while-loop that collects in each cycle all available samples from the DAQ and stores them immediately into the HDF5 file. You could imaging some real-time display during each loop cycle, but be aware of the loop duration (set `parameter[debug_output] = 3` to see some more statistics like buffer size of each cycle)

changing the boolean `hdf5_write` to False causes the code to store into Numpy array `data` which sooner or later will fills the memory. If True, all the samples are written directly into a growing HDF5 file.

```
import nidaqmx
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import h5py

def hdf5_write_parameter(h5_file, parameter, group_name='parameter'):
    # add parameter group
    param_grp = h5_file.create_group(group_name)
    # write single item
    for key, item in parameter.items():
        try:
            if item is None:
                item = 'None'
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                # recursive write each dictionary
                hdf5_write_parameter(h5_file, item, group_name+'/'+key)
            else:
                h5_file.create_dataset("/"+group_name+"/{}".format(key), data=item)
        except:
            print("[hdf5_write_parameter]: failed to write:", key, "=", item)
    return


run_bool = True # should be controlled by GUI or caller thread
measurement_duration = 1 # in seconds
filename = 'test_acquisition'
hdf5_write = True # a hdf5 file with ending '.h5' is created, False = numpy array

# check if device is available
system = nidaqmx.system.System.local()
system.driver_version
for device in system.devices:
        print(device) # plot devices
        
ADC_DEVICE_NAME = device.name # 'PCI6024e'
print('ADC: init measure for', measurement_duration, 'seconds')



# Setup ADC
parameter = { 
    "channels": 8,  # number of AI channels
    "channel_name": ADC_DEVICE_NAME + '/ai0:7',
    "log_rate": int(20000),  # Samples per second
    "adc_min_value": -5.0,  # minimum ADC value in Volts
    "adc_max_value": 5.0,  # maximum ADC value in Volts
    "timeout": measurement_duration + 2.0,  # timeout to detect external clock on read
    "debug_output": 1,
    "measurement_duration": measurement_duration,
    }

parameter["buffer_size"] = int(parameter["log_rate"])  # buffer size in samples
                           # must be bigger than loop duration!
parameter["requested_samples"] = parameter["log_rate"] * measurement_duration

parameter["hdf5_write"] = hdf5_write  # write in array
if parameter['hdf5_write']:
    filename += '.h5'
    f = h5py.File(filename, 'w') # create a h5-file object if True
    data = f.create_dataset('data', (0, parameter["channels"]), 
                                 maxshape=(None, parameter["channels"]), chunks=True)
else:
    filename += '.csv'
    # pre-allocate array, we might get up to 1 buffer more than requested...
    data = np.empty((parameter["requested_samples"]+parameter["buffer_size"], parameter["channels"]), dtype=np.float64)
    data[:] = np.nan


with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan(parameter["channel_name"],
                                         terminal_config=nidaqmx.constants.TerminalConfiguration.RSE,
                                         min_val=parameter["adc_min_value"],
                                         max_val=parameter["adc_max_value"],
                                         units=nidaqmx.constants.VoltageUnits.VOLTS
                                         )

    task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate=parameter["log_rate"],
                                    sample_mode=nidaqmx.constants.AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS)

    # helper variables
    total_samples = 0
    i = 0
    last_display = -1

    parameter["acquisition_start"] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    if 1:
        print("ADC:   ---   acquisition started:", parameter["acquisition_start"])
        print("ADC: Requested samples:", parameter["requested_samples"], "Acquisition duration:",
                      measurement_duration)


    task.control(nidaqmx.constants.TaskMode.TASK_COMMIT)
    time_adc_start = time.perf_counter()
    # ############################# READING LOOP ##########################
    while run_bool and total_samples < parameter["requested_samples"] and time.perf_counter() - time_adc_start < parameter[
        "timeout"]:
        i = i + 1

        if parameter["debug_output"] >= 1:
            elapsed_time = np.floor(time.perf_counter() - time_adc_start)  # in sec
            if elapsed_time != last_display:
                print("ADC: ...", round(elapsed_time), "of", measurement_duration, "sec:",
                              total_samples, "acquired ...")
                last_display = elapsed_time

    
        # high-lvl read function: always create a new array
        data_buff = np.asarray(
            task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=nidaqmx.constants.READ_ALL_AVAILABLE)).T
        time_adc_end = time.perf_counter()

        samples_from_buffer = data_buff.shape[0]

        # get nr of samples and acumulate to total_samples
        total_samples = int(total_samples + samples_from_buffer)
        if parameter["debug_output"] >= 2:
            print("ADC: iter", i, "total:", total_samples, "smp from buffer", samples_from_buffer,
                          "time elapsed", time.perf_counter() - time_adc_start)
        if samples_from_buffer > 0:
            
            # prepair buffer and hdf5 dataset
            if parameter["hdf5_write"]:  # sequential write to hdf5 file
                chunk_start = data.shape[0]
                # resize dataset in file
                data.resize(data.shape[0] + samples_from_buffer, axis=0)
            else:
                # prepair buffer to fit in pre-allocated array 'data'
                chunk_start = int(np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(data)) / parameter["channels"])
                if parameter['channels'] == 1:
                    data_buff = data_buff[:, np.newaxis]
            
            if parameter["debug_output"] >= 3:
                    print("Non-empty data shape: (", data.shape,
                                  "), buffer shape:", data_buff.shape,
                                  "chunk start:", chunk_start)
                    
            # write buffer to HDF5 file or into numpy array
            data[chunk_start:chunk_start + samples_from_buffer, :] = data_buff
    # ############################# READING LOOP #########################
    parameter["acquisition_stop"] = str(datetime.datetime.now())


if parameter["debug_output"] >= 1:
    print("ADC: requested points:   ", parameter["requested_samples"])
    print("ADC: total aqcuired points", total_samples, "in", time_adc_end - time_adc_start)
    print("ADC: data array shape:", data.shape)
    print("ADC:  ---   aqcuisition finished:", parameter["acquisition_stop"])
    print("ADC: sample rate:", round(1/((time_adc_end-time_adc_start)/parameter["requested_samples"])))

# prepare data nparray for return
if not parameter["hdf5_write"]:
    # shrink numpy array by all nan's (from oversize with buffer size)
    total_written = int(np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(data)) / parameter["channels"])
    if parameter["debug_output"] >= 2:
        print("resize data array by cutting", data.shape[0] - total_written, "tailing NaN's")
    data = np.resize(data, (total_written, parameter["channels"]))

# add more parameter to wrtie into the hdf5 file
parameter["total_samples"] = total_samples
parameter["total_acquisition_time"] = time_adc_end - time_adc_start
parameter["data_shape"] = data.shape
if parameter['hdf5_write']:
    hdf5_write_parameter(f, parameter) # write parameter
    f.close()
```